# Where can i find the mongoexport command in suse os?

Tags: mongoexport

When i install the mongodb with the command `zypper in mongo`, then i got mongodb 4.2 installed in my os. 
Few days after, i am gonner to backup the data in db. But i can not find the command `mongoexport`.

When i try to install it with the comand `zypper se mongoexport`, i got nothing

The version of mongodb is 3.4.10

```
host1:/usr/bin # mongo -host 127.0.0.1 -port 2222
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:2222/
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
```

I will appriciate it so much if anyone provide some method to install the command.

Comment: do `which mongo` and check in the resultant `bin` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of mongodb is too old, when i upgrade to mongodb 4.2, it contains the mongoexport/mongoimport tools in it.